# R: Modify an internal variable accessed by triple colon ":::"?

Tags: r, function, operators

I would like to modify an internal variable of an R package accessed by a triple colon.

I can do it manually by using the function `trace`. For example:

```
trace (R package:::FunctionPackage, edit=T)
```

The problem is that I have to do it everytime I restart the R session. Then, I would like to know if I could change it directly from the package or even to create a function that overlaps the one provided by the R package.

I tried with the R code: `Rpackage:::FunctionPackage <- my.function`, but it does not work.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can edit the source code of the package directly.

Comment: Ruben, trying to unlock and alter the state of the variables and functions in an installed package seems kludgy, and is fraught with problems. I really suggest that if you must have an altered function in that package, do as Gregor suggests: clone/download the source, change the function, optionally update the version within `DESCRIPTION`, and then install the source package.